# How to load/fetch the next data batches for the next epoch, during the current epoch?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I know that since PyTorch 1.7.0 it is possible to [prefetch](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.0/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) some batches **before** an epoch begins. However, this does not make it possible to fetch batches while the operations within an epoch are being performed and before the next epoch begins. Based on [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multi-process-data-loading-and-prefetching/98997/3), it seems that it should be possible to use a [Sampler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Sampler) to load batches during an epoch, and before the next epoch begins. However, I cannot wrap my head around how I can use a Sampler to achieve this.

Can anyone provide a code sample for a Sampler that allows fetching samples during an epoch?

Answer (score 1):

You can prefetch the next batches from iterator in a background thread.

```
class _ThreadedIterator(threading.Thread):
    """
    Prefetch the next queue_length items from iterator in a background thread.

    Example:
    >> for i in bg_iterator(range(10)):
    >>     print(i)
    """

    class _End:
        pass

    def __init__(self, generator: Iterable, maxsize: int) -> None:
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue: Queue = Queue(maxsize)
        self.generator = generator
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self) -> None:
        for item in self.generator:
            self.queue.put(item)
        self.queue.put(self._End)

    def __iter__(self) -> Any:
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> Any:
        next_item = self.queue.get()
        if next_item == self._End:
            raise StopIteration
        return next_item

    # Required for Python 2.7 compatibility
    def next(self) -> Any:
        return self.__next__()


def bg_iterator(iterable: Iterable, maxsize: int) -> Any:
    return _ThreadedIterator(iterable, maxsize=maxsize)
```

**UPD**.
Usage:

```
model = model.to(device, non_blocking=True)
for inputs, targets in bg_iterator(data_loader, maxsize=2):
    inputs = inputs.to(device, non_blocking=True)
    targets = targets.to(device, non_blocking=True)
```

[example](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/blob/14dd917ec60fa69ce3f7c6e3f2eaf520e67928b5/examples/pipeline_wavernn/main.py#L184)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Would this mean that each process of the DataLoader would itself create another thread? Wouldn't this cause the DataLoader to have too many threads? I'm asking this because it is highly recommended not to have more threads than the total number of CPU threads

Comment: Also, what do you think about the Sampler approach that the PyTorch developer mentioned? Do you know how to fetch new batches using a Sampler?

Comment: You are right, that in the each spawned process `bg_iteator` creates a separate thread to prefetch the data. It's not recomended to use threads for CPU-bound tasks because of GIL. You can use a bunch of threads for IO tasks but it's another topic of discussion.
In this example, if you use GPU and set `.to(device, non_blocking=True)` to model and performed tensors, you will get a speedup improvement because of copying is non-blocking and inference is processed on GPU. Meanwhile, the background thread still continues prefetching data on CPU.

Comment: Sampler is responsible to draw indexes from a dataset, it doesn't perform fetching. The PyTorch developer mentioned that you can pass a custom sampler to force a certain pattern in the content of the batch (meaning you can create a custom order of sample indexes for a new batch). "And thus what the workers will load". The worker in this context can be a separate thread/process.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your solution at some point and accept it as answer if things work fine. I hope this is okay with you